# Colcon build error : 0 packages finished

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-humble, colcon, windows

I am using ROS2 humble on Windows 10 and it is installed successfully. Now I am going through this tutorial for creating a workspace:
https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Creating-A-Workspace/Creating-A-Workspace.html

But while I am using the “colcon build --merge install” command I face the following error message:

```
Failed <<< turtlesim [9.41s, exited with code 1]

Summary: 0 packages finished [9.75s]
1 package failed: turtlesim
1 package had stderr output: turtlesim
WNDPROC return value cannot be converted to LRESULT
TypeError: WPARAM is simple, so must be an int object (got NoneType)
```

You can see the full error message here:

[image]

however, it creates the “build, install and log folder” on my workspace, and also “ros2 run turtlesim turtlesim_node” opens the turtlesim.

It seems that the turtlesim package comes pre-built along with the ros2 installation and it is not calling the turtlesim package on my ros2_ws at all. So, when I modify the overlay like this:

https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Creating-A-Workspace/Creating-A-Workspace.html#modify-the-overlay

Nothing has happened; this is about 1 week I am stuck in this step, could anyone help me in this regard? I should mention that I installed “em”, “empty” and none of them fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by uninstalling "Python 3.12, 64-bit version" which had been installed on my system because I found the CMake error refers to a Python 3.12 on my system and I didn't know why it should have existed on my system (During ROS2 installation I had installed python 3.8, not 3.12). So, I called the following command in the command prompt, and I was assured an extra Python version was installed on my system:

```
> py -0
```

which returned:

```
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
-3.8-64 *
-3.12-64
```

I decided to uninstall version 3.12 so that ROS2 just uses Python 3.8. Fortunately, it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your build error message, it looks like you're missing a Python package. I found this https://answers.ros.org/question/257757/importerror-no-module-named-em-error/, which seems to have multiple ways to resolve this missing package. As you say you have installed it, you might need to check your python path so that the `empy` module can be found.

The turtlesim package comes pre-built when you installed ROS 2. If your build was successful, then you could overlay your turtlesim on the built-in one. As your build has not been successful, there is no binary file in your overlay, so the system uses the pre-built one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Based on the links you shared, I installed empy with "python3 -m pip install empy" command and now it is installed successfully by returning the following message: 
Successfully built empy
Installing collected packages: empy
Successfully installed empy-3.3.4

. Also I installed catkin_pkg with "pip install catkin_pkg" which returned to me "Requirement already satisfied" 

but now I have a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'catkin_pkg'" error message when I am using "colcon build --merge-install" command.

Comment: I don't have Windows, so I can't check, but it could be that you installed the python2 version of `catkin_pkg`. Your initial console output shows that you're using python3 to build your packages, so you'll want to ensure you're installing the python3 version of everything. You did that for `empy` alreardy.